# Check if route exists when Route::fallback present

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am attempting to determine if a given route exists while inside of Laravel's `Route::fallback`. The following snippet *should* throw a `NotFoundHttpException` exception, however I suspect that it is not due to the presence of the fallback (ie, the route does exist as a fallback).

```php
Route::fallback(function () use ($routes) {
    try {
        $next = Request::create('does-not-exist');
        Route::getRoutes()->match($next);
    } catch (NotFoundHttpException) {
        // Should end up here
    }
});
```

For some context: I'd like to be able to hit a route that does exist and then display the contents of another route. This second route may end up not actually existing and I'd like to be able to catch that.

TIA

Comment: You can handle 404 Exception in `App\Exceptions`

Comment: I'm aware of that but the request the user makes will be to a legitimate route and then shown content from another route. There is no opportunity for a 404 exception to be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `Route::getRoutes()->match($next);` will be an `Illuminate\Routing\Route` object. You can check this object for the value of the [`isFallback` property](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L52).

```php
Route::fallback(function () use ($routes) {
    $next = Request::create('does-not-exist');
    $route = Route::getRoutes()->match($next);
    if ($route->isFallback) {
        // do your thing
    }
});
```